# How can I play YouTube in the background without using Safari?

Tags: ios, applications, youtube

Is there an easy way to keep playing YouTube videos in the background, even if I switch to a different app?

I'm not interested in using [the Safari multitasking trick](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/106281/72620). I want something super easy to use.

Comment: @Gerry Not realky: Ive specified I need an app, and not using Safari. Check the other question

Comment: The other question lists an answer for using the default Youtube app too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On iOS 5.1 (not sure for earlier versions) the [same procedure](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/41444/14994) works for the YouTube app too (as for Safari):

- Start the video in the YouTube app.
- Press "Home" button once to go to springboard (or twice to switch to another app)
- Press "Home" button **twice** to bring up the app-switcher. Slide to the right to bring up background audio controls. The icon on the right side will show whichever program you last used with background audio: YouTube.
- Press Play. YouTube audio will resume playback.