# Can I play YouTube video in background on iPad ?

Tags: ipad, applications, music, youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [An app to play youtube in background on ipad](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43784/an-app-to-play-youtube-in-background-on-ipad)

If I want to listen to a Youtube video and work on another app, such as Safari, is there a way for that audio to run in the background like iTunes does?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/43784/14994

Comment: Use Jasmine. Great app & interface.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Ermiar said, yes, but if the app in the foreground wants to play music or sounds itself, the sound from the Youtube app will be stopped.

Also, the Youtube app can, like iTunes, continue t play if you lock your iPad with the lock key, and you can also control it by double clicking the home button while the iPad is locked.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the YouTube app to play your video and then switch to another app, YouTube will be in background like iTunes does.

You can control the YouTube video by double clicking the home button then swipe to left on the multitask drawer to access controls.