# Is there a way to play YouTube videos in the background?

Tags: ios, youtube

I remember that once upon a time I was able to start a song on the YouTube app (or Jasmine), then go and do other things on the phone.

That doesn't seem possible anymore with iOS 10.  Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! You only need to enter from safari and not from the app. You choose the song you want to listen to, press the home button, swipe up to multitask and press play!

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I don't think we can its because YouTube isn't a pre-installed app like it used to be, however there may be a app that can allow you to but I doubt it. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can all you've to do is play the youtube video in Safari and >> hit home button >> double tap the home button >> and from the fast access/ quick launch you can press the play button...
for more further details i've found this link you can check here though happy youtubing !!!
[Details on how to play youtube videos in background on iOS Apple iDevices](http://www.gizmodimension.com/play-youtube-videos-background-on-apple-iphone-ipad/)