# Picture in Picture on YouTube app

Tags: iphone, youtube, picture-in-picture

How to enable Picture in Picture option on YouTube app for iPhone ?
I have enabled picture in picture option in accessibility i can use it on Netflix app and prime videos so on but im not able to use on YouTube app please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube disables PIP unless you are a premium subscriber to YouTube.

There are 3rd party apps available which support it

[How can I run a YouTube video in Picture in Picture mode on iOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/347584/how-can-i-run-a-youtube-video-in-picture-in-picture-mode-on-ios)